# How to implement multi-threading on this simple database information return

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite

Any ideas how to implement multi-threading on this?? The return values are causing me issues when trying to implement a simple thread.

```
//Retrieving information from database
public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseOperations dop) {
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {TableData.TableInfo.KEY_activity, TableData.TableInfo.KEY_date, TableData.TableInfo.KEY_hour, TableData.TableInfo.KEY_minute, TableData.TableInfo.KEY_second, TableData.TableInfo.KEY_distance};
    Cursor CR = SQ.query(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    return CR;
}
```

Comment: make your DB class a singleton, lock around all write operations.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into AsyncTask, or the HAMMER framework which stands for Handlers, Messages and Runnables.

Here is an example of spawing a new Thread, and using a Runnable to do the work, then post a callback function call to send back the results.

```
interface DbOperation{
   void onQueryResult(Cursor c);
}

//Retrieving information from database
public void getInformation(final DatabaseOperations dop, final DbOperation callback) {

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
            String[] columns = {TableData.TableInfo.KEY_activity, 
               TableData.TableInfo.KEY_date, TableData.TableInfo.KEY_hour, 
               TableData.TableInfo.KEY_minute, TableData.TableInfo.KEY_second, 
               TableData.TableInfo.KEY_distance};
             Cursor CR = SQ.query(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
           callback.onQueryResult(CR);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

then when calling the method:

```
 getInformation(dop, new DbOperation(){
    @Override
    public void onQueryResult(Cursor c){
        if(c == null)
           return;
        // .. use the cursor, make sure to use Handler or runOnUiThread method
        // since this call will run on a Background thread and you can't update
        // the UI from a background thread
    }
 });
```

Good Luck and Happy Coding!